# Read a line from a file on a specific commit in C#

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I am trying to capture a specific line in a file given a FilePath, LineNumber, and the CommitID (Hash) for that file repo I have stored locally. I have it working except for I have not been able to access a specify Commit yet. I am currently looking into LibGit2Sharp for the implementation.

Currently I have:

```
using System.IO;
...
string lineContent;
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
if (lineNumber > 0 && lineNumber <= lines.Length)
{
    lineContent = lines[lineNumber - 1].Trim();
}
```

I have a Commit hash similarly to this one: "bc1fd7e96dabd2a3180e5fe7146885208c12f279"

How would I:
First specify I would like to access this commit at the root repo directory.
Then go to the given file path of that "Repo" in my local files and copy the line from the file that is associated with this commit ID?

Comment: Ignore the "read a specific line" part - focus on getting to a specific Commit, and then getting to the Blob for a given path. At the moment you haven't shown us *anything* about how far you've got with libgit2sharp, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Reason be is I have not gotten anywhere with libgit2sharp. I am not sure the nuances of the library and I was not able to find it's documentation. It's git page says to reference stackoverflow for help...

Comment: Okay, then that's the first step, rather than leaping to "I want to get to a specific line in a file." http://www.woodwardweb.com/git/getting_started_2.html will at least give you some starting points - and I'm sure there are other tutorials too.

Comment: And the wiki page at https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/LibGit2Sharp-Hitchhiker%27s-Guide-to-Git is useful too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the Contents of a specific file at a given path within a Repo Using LibGit2Sharp, given a specific Commit RSA ID. You would need to do something like this:

```
string lineContent;

Repository repo = new Repository(@"C:\Path");
Commit commit = repo.Lookup<Commit>("CommitHashID");
string[] paths = "Directory/SubDirectory/FilePath.extension".Split('/');
string fullPath = paths[0];
Tree tree = commit.Tree;
TreeEntry entry = tree.First(x => x.Path == fullPath);
if(entry.TargetType == TreeEntryTargetType.Tree)
{
    foreach(string pathPart in paths.Skip(1).ToArray())
    {
        if(entry.TargetType == TreeEntryTargetType.Tree)
            tree = (Tree)entry.Target;

        fullPath += "/" + pathPart;
        entry = tree.First(x => x.Path == fullPath);
    }
}
LibGit2Sharp.Blob blob = (LibGit2Sharp.Blob)entry.Target;
string[] lines = blob.GetContentText().Split(new char[] { '\n' });

if (lineNumber > 0 && lineNumber <= lines.Length)
{
    lineContent = lines[lineNumber - 1].Trim();
}
```